# Sending a file in POST in react (request api)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

So, I'm trying to use some api to sign some documents. But for that, I need to POST a file in the request body. I tried by directly sending file object in json format, but server doesn't seem to recognise it. Any ideas?

The response is : Error 400 "Missing required parameter file in an uploaded file"

```
getPendingFile = (apikey)=>{
    var request = require("request");

        var options = { 
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api-ext.getsigneasy.com/v1/files/original/',
            headers:{
                Authorization : 'Bearer '+apikey,

            },
            json:true,

            body:{
                'name':this.state.file_name,
                file:this.state.ipfile //I want to POST this file to the api

            }   
        };

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) 
                throw new Error(error);

            console.log(body);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use multipart/form-data to send files.

The request package you are using has good documentation on this.
https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads

```
const formData = {
  name: this.state.file_name,
  file: this.state.ipfile 
};
request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('upload failed:', err);
  }
  console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

Comment: getting this error:
------------------------------------
TypeError: self._form.on is not a function
Request.push../node_modules/request/request.js.Request.form
node_modules/request/request.js:1355